# Geometry nodes: Setting the Position of an Object based on the Position of an instance

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I would like to reveal a text by slicing a string, and I would like an object to appear right next to the last revealed character (something like a cursor). I tried to capture the position of the last revealed instance and use it to change the position of the cursor like this:

[image: Geometry node view]

but the "cursor" is not moving at all.
Tried it in Blender 3.4.1 and 3.5 Alpha.
Where is my mistake?
Is it a lack of understanding how the Geometry Nodes workflow works or did I just miss something?
I would be happy if you could point me in the right direction, even if you can't solve the problem.
Suggestions about which tutorials would make sens are also appreciated.

Comment: you would attract much more people (lazy ones as me) if you would provide a blend file....the task is easy, but i am too lazy to build all on my own

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. For some reason that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the sample index node to capture the position of the last displayed character.